# SQL Server errors in trigger that locks table lost with SqlDataAdapter and ambient transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, error-handling, transactions, transactionscope

Okay, so I've run into a rather bizarre circumstance. There are several layers to my situation. I haven't identified whether every layer is strictly required, but here's what's going on:

- C# code is creating an ambient transaction, into which a `SqlConnection` is automatically enlisting.
- C# code is using a `SqlDataAdapter` to insert a row into a table.
- The `InsertCommand` is referencing a stored procedure. The stored procedure is a straightforward `INSERT` statement.
- The table into which the `INSERT` is being done has a trigger on it `INSTEAD OF INSERT`.
- The trigger obtains an exclusive lock on the table.
- An error occurs within the trigger.

With this conjunction, the error is not raised within the C# code. However, if the trigger does *not* obtain an exclusive lock on the table, the error does make it up to the C# code.

The error *is* actually happening, though, evidenced by the fact that on the SQL Server side, the transaction has been aborted. The C# code doesn't know that the transaction has been aborted, and only encounters an error when the disposal of the `TransactionScope` tries to `COMMIT TRANSACTION`.

I have created a minimal reproduction of this scenario:

https://github.com/logiclrd/TestErrorWhileLockedInTrigger

Does anyone have any understanding of why this might be, and how proper error handling behaviour might be restored?

Comment: Anyone who had looked at this and been confused by the mismatch between `Database Initialization.sql` and the code, that's my bad. I forgot to hit `Save` before adding & committing to git. I have made a follow-up commit with the correct initialization code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have identified the cause of the problem.

The statement in the trigger locking the table looked like this:

```
SELECT TOP 0 *
  FROM TableToTriggerAndLock WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)
```

While this returns no data, it *does* return an (empty) result set. It turns out the `SqlDataAdapter` class only cares about the first result set it gets back on the TDS stream, so the error coming back in the *second* result set is completely passed over.

Take out the locking statement, and you take out that redundant result set, and now the error is in the *first* result set.

The solution, then, is to suppress the result set, which I did by reworking the locking statement as:

```
DECLARE @Dummy INT

SELECT TOP 0 @Dummy = 1
  FROM TableToTriggerAndLock WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)
```

Hope this helps someone out there working with `SqlDataAdapter` and more complicated underlying operations. :-)

Answer (score 1):

So, I've done some more testing of this.

My first thought was, if holding the exclusive lock is causing it to squelch the error, maybe explicitly releasing the lock will unsquelch it? So, I put a `TRY`/`CATCH` around the statement that generates the error in my proof-of-concept, had it `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` and then re-`THROW`, but it didn't do anything.

So then my next thought was, the `RAISERROR` statement, when used with severity levels 20-25, forcibly terminates the connection. I'm not sure if this is an ideal solution, because it also writes an entry to the SQL Server event log when this happens. However, it *does* achieve the goal of having the `SqlDataAdapter` see the error during its `Update` command instead of the C# code thinking the transaction is still active and trying to commit it.

Does anyone know of other potential downsides to this "sledgehammer" approach, or is it possibly going to be the only way to get the error to propagate properly in this circumstance?